# Wordpress the_category() reverse order so parents come first?

Tags: wordpress

A template i'm using is calling the_category() to list the categories which a post belongs to. It's ordering them by default with the child name first then parents. Is there a way to reverse the order so that the categories are listed as Parent, Child, Second Child?

Answer (score 3):

You could filter get_the_terms and modify the results to suit your needs. You will need to add or remove the filter or use a conditional to only modify this where you need it. Here is an example for reversing the order of the retrieved terms.

```
function reverse_categories($terms, $id, $taxonomy){
    if($taxonomy == 'category'){
        $terms = array_reverse($terms, true);
    }
    return $terms;
}
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'reverse_categories', 10, 3);
```

Comment: the 10 is a priority flag, 10 is default for filtering. 3 is for the number of arguments that you want to bring into the function. In this case you need number 3 to make sure you are looking at the category taxonomy.

Comment: Hi, I ended up using yoast seo which has breadcrumbs built in that list the categories in parent child order, and left the_category() as is, but thank you for the help / suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a one-liner without creating a function/filter wherever you may implement get_the_category_list() function:

`implode(', ',array_reverse(explode(',',get_the_category_list(','))))`

Change the implode string to one of your choice if you don't want ", ".

I can personally confirm this works in WordPress 3.5 -- but i am sure it will work in just about any version of WordpPress since 1.5.2 when get_the_category_list() was introduced.